# Calling php file on load in aspx

Tags: php, asp.net

I created a comment system using php and would like to implement it in my aspx page. The problem is im not sure how to run the php code on load from my aspx page. I can call the php after the page has been loaded via javascript but I would like for it to load at the same time with the page. So is it possible to call my php script on load from my aspx page?

Comment: OH **GOD**, why? Why, PLEASE, tell me why?

Comment: I'm using ajax but Ive been using it to call it after its been loaded which causes comments to magically appear after a few seconds of the page being loaded which doesn't look great.

Comment: @PiLHA I tried iframe it still has that flash from being loaded after the page was created though.

Comment: Use an earlier event in the lifecycle of create page to call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am little confused as your question is not very clear. If you cant use iframe, (because it gets loaded after the page has loaded) then replace it with a literal control. In your page load event get the output of the php page as

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.asp.net/blabla.php");
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

update the literal value with the html. I dont know what will be the behaviour after postback from php page because mine page dosent do any postback.
But this will ensure that php has been rendered in load event itself.

Comment: This works thanks. That I noticed there was no problem with postback.